# OpenCL - Understanding the output of CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE and CL_KERNEL_PRIVATE_MEM_SIZE

Tags: opencl

According to the  `clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo` documentation (from [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo.html)), I tried to query the work group size & private memory size used by my kernel. Tested the below snippet on an Android device with adreno 530 GPU.

(Code sample from [Apple OpenCL tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/UsingGCDwOpenCL/UsingGCDwOpenCL.html))

```
size_t maxWorkGroupSize;
cl_ulong private_mem_used;
clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(kernel, &device, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(maxWorkGroupSize), &maxWorkGroupSize, NULL );
clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(kernel, &device, CL_KERNEL_PRIVATE_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(private_mem_used), &private_mem_used, NULL );

printf("Max work-group size is %ld \n", maxWorkGroupSize);
printf("Private memory used is %lld KB\n", private_mem_used/1024);
```

Output:

```
Max work-group size is 42773336 
Private memory used is 179412930700111 KB
```

The output seems to be not correct.

1. If the output is not correct, is there anything wrong in the snippet?
2. If the output is correct, it will be helpful if you could help in interpreting the output

Comment: Are you sure the calls to `clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo ` are returning `CL_SUCCESS`? Your device argument seems suspicious, are you sure you need to pass in `&device` and note `device` without the address-of operator? (You don't show the declaration or how you obtain its value, so I can only guess.)

Comment: You're correct, "&device" was the problem. When I passed just "device" I got the correct CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE. However CL_KERNEL_PRIVATE_MEM_SIZE returns 0 always. But the kernels have arrays declared within them. Won't they be promoted to private memory implicitly without "__private" identifier?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with wrong values seems to be resolved in the comment of user @pmdj.

I'm referring here to why you may seemingly always get value 0 returned for parameter name CL_KERNEL_PRIVATE_MEM_SIZE.

The things is, values returned for parameter name CL_KERNEL_PRIVATE_MEM_SIZE vary on different platforms.

On some they return the amount or private memory used - so the amount of bytes needed to store all variables in registers. Note that compiler does optimizations so it does not have to equal to the sum of your variables' sizes.

On other platforms it returns the amount or private memory spilled. So if you use too many variables and you exceed the size of your registers the compiler has to spill memory into caches or global memory. You can monitor this value when you make changes to your kernel. If it starts spilling, it's likely your kernel will become slower - often much slower. The amount spilled can be reported in bytes or in registers amount - which can be amount of 32-bit words.